# Problem with Sequelize Transaction including in model query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've defined a database file where the sequelize databases are been defined. In the controller function, I'm creating transactions from the imported defined sequelize database and passing them to the Model operations like findOne or update or something. Later I've other lines of code where if anything goes wrong rollback will be done.
But here the problem is with transactions passed to the Model. If I remove a transaction in the model query, it is extracting the user information but with the transaction, I'm getting `ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist at character 89`

```
//database file
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import config from './config/config.js'

const {database} = config

const userSequelize = new Sequelize(database.user.name, database.user.user, database.user.password, {
  host: database.user.host,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: false,
});


const transactionSequelize = new Sequelize(database.transaction.name, database.transaction.user, database.transaction.password, {
  host: database.transaction.host,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: false
})


export {
  userSequelize,
  transactionSequelize
};

//Controller file
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import User from '../models/user.js';
import { transactionSequelize } from '../database.js';
import Transaction from '../models/transaction.js';

const transferMoney = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    await Transaction.sync();
    const transaction = await transactionSequelize.transaction();
    try {
        const { transferFrom, transferTo, amount } = req.body;
        const receiverExists = await User.findOne({
            where: {
                id: transferTo
            },
            transaction: transaction //problem here
        });
        if (!receiverExists) {
            res.status(404).send({ message: "Receiver not found" });
        }
        //need to implement rest of the code

    } catch (error) {
        await transaction.rollback();
        res.status(500).send({ message: "Server Error" });
    }
}

export default {
    transferMoney,
}
```

Comment: Can you add `logging: console.log` to `findOne` options to see the generated SQL and examine it?

Comment: The query is perfectly fine but looks the user's table is not accessible via transaction. Idk how. If you need any extra file info you can view it in this repo "https://github.com/bhanuprakashwar/bank-backend"

Comment: You mentioned that you have several Sequelize connections. Could it be that a passed transaction was from another connection to a DB that does not have Users table?

Comment: Yes! It is a different connection DB running in a different port. But if you see the `createUser` method in `userController.ts`, I'm creating the user in userDB and also creating a record in balanceDB. I thought there is no need to define an relation as they were working but in transaction things are different

Comment: Could you also show the models as well?

Comment: It seems you tyr to use the transaction from `transactionSequelize` in the model that is connected to `usersSequelize`

Comment: Just use the transaction from the same Sequelize instance where you have the model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253071/discussion-between-bhanu-prakash-war-and-anatoly).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to passing the wrong sequelize transaction instance. Here Im passing `const transaction = await transactionSequelize.transaction();` to the User query which is wrong. Here I should pass the user transaction instance.

```
const transferMoney = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
const userT = await userSequelize.transaction();
    await Transaction.sync();
    const transaction = await transactionSequelize.transaction();
    try {
        const { transferFrom, transferTo, amount } = req.body;
        const receiverExists = await User.findOne({
            where: {
                id: transferTo
            },
            transaction: userT //This is the correction
        });
        if (!receiverExists) {
            res.status(404).send({ message: "Receiver not found" });
        }
        //need to implement rest of the code like writing transactionDB query

    } catch (error) {
        await transaction.rollback();
        res.status(500).send({ message: "Server Error" });
    }
}
```